# String Replacing

Tags: intersystems-cache, mumps

In your opinion what would be the best way to replace something in a string without using $R? I've written a global and I'm trying to replace PETER(s) with PAUL, but not use $R. Here's what iteration of what I thought would work, but it just replaces the first PETER. What would you guys suggest, for multiple Peters on the same line?

```
Start  
SET ary="^XA"
SET queryary=$QUERY(@ary@(""))
WRITE !,@queryary
FOR   {
SET queryary=$QUERY(@queryary) 
    QUIT:queryary=""  
    w !,$p(@queryary,"PETER",1)_"PAUL"_$p(@queryary,"PETER",2,$l(@queryary,"PETER"))  

}
  QUIT
```

This is my second try, but I still have to run it multiple times for it to perform all the changes. Is there something missing in my Loop?

```
  Start  
  N ary
  S ary="^XA"
  S queryary=$Q(@ary@(""))
  S FROM="PETER"
  S TO="PAUL"
  W !,@queryary
  F   S queryary=$Q(@queryary) Q:queryary=""  w !,@queryary   d 
  . f  s $E(@queryary,$F(@queryary,FROM)-$L(FROM),$F(@queryary,FROM))=TO_" "     Q:ary'["PETER"  
  QUIT
```

Comment: So thus far, with some doing some reading on $Q and Indirection I have been able to figure out the following

Comment: `without using $R`? $R[ANDOM] ?

Comment: You had this XNAME global in the question before )

Comment: HAHA yes I did, then I began looking some stuff up, and rewrote everything. Trying to become a programmer and M being my first real language has had some challenges.

Comment: Are you required to use ANSI M/Mumps (like Epic programmers have to do), are are you allowed to use the many language enhancements that have been done over the last 20 years in Caché ObjectScript? Personally, I tried to avoid ANSI Mumps like the plague, but COS was a decent language for rapid application development [but I might be biased, having spend 29 years implementing it!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in Cache and want a utility for this, %GCHANGE is a very powerful program just for doing what you described. I've always used it as a utility and never called it from a program but I believe there are labels where you an call and pass in your parameters.

The other thing is that you are using multiple indirections in a loop which will slow down your program. I suggest combining all of that into a string and use the E(X)ecute command for indirection on the entire string. You can see the example provided below.

I included two different methods of replacing string. One uses $P and $L similar to what [Evgeny Shvarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2604018/evgeny-shvarov) suggested and the second method is using $F and $E.

The second method on average performed 33% faster on a global of 100000 nodes and 4 replacement per node.

I will include my data gen. and testing functions I wrote as well. I wrote these in legacy MUMPS code so it would work cross platform.

UPDATE: I just checked GTM documentation. %GCE is a similar utility that is avialable in GTM.
UPDATE: I Change the REPLACE function to properly account for the LISA to ELISA problem described by [C4xuxo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2290179/c4xuxo). It still performs faster than using $P $L.

UPDATE: Made an adjustment to the value of PS in the REPLACE function to fix a bug;

```
;GLOBAL REPLACE METHOD 
GLBREPLACE(GLB,STR1,STR2) ;(GLOBAL NAME, STRING TO MATCH, STRING TO REPLACE WITH)
 S CMD="N I S I="""" F  S I=$O("_GLB_"(I)) Q:I=""""  S "_GLB_"(I)=$$REPLACE("_GLB_"(I),"""_STR1_""","""_STR2_""")"
 X CMD Q

;STRING REPLACE METHOD
REPLACE(STR,V1,V2) ;(INPUT STRING, STRING TO MATCH, STRING TO REPLACE WITH)
 N I,L,F1,F2,PS S PS=0,L=$L(STR,V1) F I=1:1:L-1 S F2=$F(STR,V1,PS),F1=F2-$L(V1),$E(STR,F1,F2-1)=V2,PS=F2+$L(V2) 
 Q STR



;======================================================================
;ADDITINAL FUNCTIONS

;THIS IS AN ALTERNATE METHOD, DOESN'T ADDRESS THE LISA TO ELISA PROBLEM
REPLACE2(STR,V1,V2) 
 N I F I=1:1:$L(STR,V1)-1 S STR=$P(STR,V1)_V2_$P(STR,V1,2,$L(STR,V1))
 Q STR

TESTGLBREPLACE ;THIS FUNCTION TESTS GLBREPLACE AND MEASURS PERFORMANCE
 S STIM=$ZTS S COUNT=100000
 D GENDATA(COUNT),GLBREPLACE("^XA","Peter","PAUL")
 S ETIM=$ZTS,TIMDIF=$P(ETIM,",",2)-$P(STIM,",",2),OCCURS=COUNT*4
 W !,"REPLACED "_OCCURS_" OCCURRENCES IN "_TIMDIF_" SECONDS"
 Q

GENDATA(L) ;THIS FUNCTION GENERATES DATA FOR A GIVE COUNT(L=INTEGER)
 F I=1:1:L S ^XA(I)="Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers; A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked; If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers, Where's the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked"
 Q
```

Comment: This is really awesome, I've learned so much from you all. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Without using $replace is tricky. I used the $find and $extract functions... mine replaces "MOZART" with "BACH"

```
mozartdocument
s ^XA(1)="ONCE UPON A TIME A COMPOSER NAMED MOZART WROTE"
s ^XA(2)="THE 'MOZART PIANO CONCERTO NUMBER ONE'. MOZART"
s ^XA(3)="MOZART 12 MOZART HANDEL MOZART MOZART 12"
s ^XA(4)="MAN MOZART MUMPS MANY MUNCHKINS MOZART"
s ^XA(5)="MOVE ALONG, NOTHING TO SEE HERE!"
s ^XA(6)="123 MOZART 456"
s ^XA(7)="HAPPILY EVER AFTER!"

for z = 1:1:7 {
    do {
        set x = $find(^XA(z),"MOZART")
        set $extract(^XA(z),x-6,x-1)="BACH"
    } while x > 0
    write !,^XA(z)
} write !
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
    ClassMethod PeterPaul()
{
    s ^XNAME(1)="PETER PIPER PICKED A PEPPER"
    s ^XNAME(2)="PETER ENJOYS PIZZA'. PETER" 
    s ^XNAME(3)="PETER WAS BORN IN 1982" 
    s ^XNAME(4)="PETER LIKES PIZZA AND FRENCH FRIES'. PETER" 
    s ^XNAME(5)="THE PETER WROTE A BOOK CALLED PETER ADVENTURES." 
    s ^XNAME(6)="THE PETER HAD THREE KIDS.' PETER JR AND PETER III"
    s ^XNAME(7)="PETER MARRIED MARY."
    s i=$O(^XNAME(""))
    while i'="" {
        s ^XNAME(i)=..Replace(^XNAME(i),"PETER","PAUL")
        s i=$O(^XNAME(i))
        }
    q
}

ClassMethod Replace(str, from, to As %String)
{
        while $F(str,from) {
            s str=$P(str,from)_to_$P(str,from,2,$L(str,from))
            }
        quit str
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot yet post comments, and this was supposed to be more like a comment to previous solution and a question about what is the actual mumps generated by Cache. So if someone reply and confirm my suspicious below would be great, since I think that there is a bug on previous solution.

So assuming the Cache compiles the solution below:

```
ClassMethod Replace(str, from, to As %String)
{
        while $F(str,from) {
            s str=$P(str,from)_to_$P(str,from,2,$L(str,from))
            }
        quit str
}
```

To something like this:

```
REPLACE(str,from,to)
        ;
        F I=1:1 Q:'$F(str,from)  D
        .       S str=$P(str,from)_to_$P(str,from,2,$L(str,from))
        Q str
```

There is a serious bug in this code that will result in a infinite loop when my actual `from` variable is contained in `to`,

Change for example "LISA" to "ELISA", "ELISABETH", "ALISA", "MELISA".

Example used below change DAN to DANIEL.

Tested on GTM (Loop manually interrupted after 10 iteration otherwise would be infinite):

```
GTM>W $$REPLACE^ZZTEST("DAN SMITH","DAN","DANIEL")
DANIELIELIELIELIELIELIELIELIELIEL SMITH
```

With this in mind I propose something like:

```
REPLACE2(str,from,to)
        ;
        N str2
        S str2=""
        F I=1:1:$L(str,from)-1 D
        .       S str2=str2_$P(str,from)_to
        .       S str=$P(str,from,2,$L(str,from))
        ;add the last piece if it exists or in case nothing to replace add all.
        Q str2_str
```

Tested in GTM:

```
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("DAN SMITH","DAN","DANIEL")
DANIEL SMITH
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("DAN SMITH DAN","DAN","DANIEL")
DANIEL SMITH DANIEL
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("DAN SMITH DAN DAN DAN","DAN","DANIEL")
DANIEL SMITH DANIEL DANIEL DANIEL
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("DAN SMITH DAN DAN DAN","DANA","DANIEL")
DAN SMITH DAN DAN DAN
```

Of course that will not be a final solution since it still contains bugs for example the name LISABETH is generated....

```
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISABETH SMITH","ELISA","LISA")
LISABETH SMITH
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA","ELISA","LISA")
LISA LISABETH SMITH LISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA"," ELISA","LISA")
ELISALISABETH SMITHLISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA"," ELISA ","LISA")
ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA"," ELISA","LISA")
ELISALISABETH SMITHLISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA ELISABETH SMITH ELISA","ELISA ","LISA")
LISAELISABETH SMITH ELISA
```

To bypass this problem additional logic needs to be added to understand that if the name is in the beginning needs to be "NAME " if is at end " NAME", otherwise in the middle " NAME ".

something like (that can probably be optimized):

```
REPLACE2(str,from,to)
        ;
        N from2,str2
        S str2=""
        S from2=" "_from_" "
        ; check if string begins with name
        I $E(str,1,$L(from))_" "=(from_" ") S str2=to,str=$E(str,$L(from)+1,$L(str))
        ; search for name with spaces
        F I=1:1:$L(str,from2)-1 D
        .       S str2=str2_$P(str,from2)_" "_to
        .       S str=" "_$P(str,from2,2,$L(str,from2))
        ; check if finishes with name
        I $L(str)>=$L(from) D
        .       I $E(str,$L(str)-$L(from),$L(str))=(" "_from) S str2=str2_$E(str,1,$L(str)-$L(from))_to,str=""
        .
        Q str2_str      ;add the last piece if it exists
```

Test on GTM:

```
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("MELISA ELISA ELISABETH ALISA ELISA","ELISA","LISA")
MELISA LISA ELISABETH ALISA LISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("MELISA ELISA ELISABETH ALISA ELISA","LISA","ELISA")
MELISA ELISA ELISABETH ALISA ELISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("LISA MELISA ELISA ELISABETH LISA  ALISA LISA","LISA","ELISA)
ELISA MELISA ELISA ELISABETH ELISA  ALISA ELISA
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("LISA MELISA ELISA ELISABETH LISA ALISA LISA","LISA","ELISA)
ELISA MELISA ELISA ELISABETH ELISA ALISA ELISA
```

But still may not attend to all of your needs if you decide or receive input like:

```
GTM>W $$REPLACE2^ZZTEST("ELISA,SMITH","ELISA","LISA")
ELISA,SMITH
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard REPLACE quoted in the Mumps Development Committee minutes is in $$REPLACE^XLFSTR(). I use it very frequently as a printf emulator.

```
REPLACE(IN,SPEC) ;See $$REPLACE in MDC minutes.
         Q:'$D(IN) "" Q:$D(SPEC)'>9 IN N %1,%2,%3,%4,%5,%6,%7,%8
         S %1=$L(IN),%7=$J("",%1),%3="",%6=9999 F  S %3=$O(SPEC(%3)) Q:%3=""  S %6(%6)=%3,%6=%6-1
         F %6=0:0 S %6=$O(%6(%6)) Q:%6'>0  S %3=%6(%6) D:$D(SPEC(%3))#2 RE1
         S %8="" F %2=1:1:%1 D RE3
         Q %8
         ;
RE1      S %4=$L(%3),%5=0 F  S %5=$F(IN,%3,%5) Q:%5
```

Here's the reference on how to use it:

http://hardhats.org/kernel/html/x-replace%5Exlfstr.shtml.

Comment: The entire code isn't shown unfortunately. See https://github.com/OSEHRA/VistA-M/blob/master/Packages/Kernel/Routines/XLFSTR.m.

Comment: Unless somebody is required to use ANSI Standard M/MUMPS, I'd avoid even showing that sort of 40+ year old code, it's definitely something that leads to people avoiding the language, even though better alternatives are available.  Even if you do have to use ANSI Standard M/MUMPS (either because you have to use GT/M or your employer [like Epic] requires it), that coding style, with single characters instead of spelled out command names, and local variables named %[1-8], with lots of commands on each line, should be avoided.